# Component Tree in android studio got accidently closed , so from where to reopen it?

Tags: android, android-studio

Component Tree in android studio got accidently closed , so from where to reopen it ?

i dig android studio and tried to find its solution on many places but i could not see the correct answer, so posting this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer my self , the window not resized to zero size so was not appearing and i was got irretated finding it . so i thought to paste the solution to save others time if ever some one faced the same issue.

[Streach from corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQW1Q.png)